# How to install qiskit-research in IBM quantum lab?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, dynamics

When I study ‘Dynamic decoupling’, one method is `add_dynamical_decoupling`.
Firstly I should install `qiskit_research` in my Jupyter notebook (IBM quantum lab), but when I use

```
git clone https://github.com/qiskit-research/qiskit-research.git
cd qiskit-research
pip install .
```

Then there is an error.
[image]

Does anyone know how to using this ‘qiskit-research’?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [change directory command does not work when used with a bang](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/the-change-directory-command-does-not-work-when-used-with-a-bang/10918). Replacing `!` with `%` should fix your problem.

```
%cd qiskit-research
%pip install .
```

You can also do `!cd qiskit-research && pip install .` to run all the commands in the same shell instance.